# How can I parse JSON in Google App Engine?

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine

I'd like to parse a JSON string into an object under Google App Engine (python).  What do you recommend?  Something to encode/stringify would be nice too.  Is what you recommend built in, or a library that I have to include in my app?  Is it secure?  Thanks.

Comment: What version if Python is on your stack?

Comment: I'm using app engine version 1, which should be python 2.5.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Consider using [Django's json lib](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/), which is included with GAE.

```
from django.utils import simplejson as json

# load the object from a string
obj = json.loads( string )
```

The link above has examples of Django's serializer, and here's the link for [simplejson's documentation](http://simplejson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/simplejson-2.0.9/docs/index.html).

If you're looking at storing Python class instances or objects (as opposed to compositions of lists, strings, numbers, and dictionaries), you probably want to look at [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html).

Incidentally, to get Django 1.0 (instead of Django 0.96) running on GAE, you can use the following call in your main.py, per [this article](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries.html#Django):

```
from google.appengine.dist import use_library
use_library('django', '1.0')
```

---

### Edit: Native JSON support in Google App Engine 1.6.0 with Python 2.7

As of Google App Engine 1.6.0, you can [use the Python 2.7 runtime](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/python27/using27.html) by adding `runtime: python27` in `app.yaml`, and then you can import the native JSON library with `import json`.

Comment: Great answer, it helped me a lot. Just a comment here: When I use the import json feature, I get a 500 Server Error when deploying my app. But when I use the from django.utils import simplejson as json it works perfectly.

Answer (score 22):

Google App Engine now supports python 2.7. If using python 2.7, you can do the following:

```
import json
structured_dictionary = json.loads(string_received)
```

Answer (score 6):

Include the [simplejson](http://www.undefined.org/python/) library with your app?

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but I thought I'd give an updated, more detailed answer. For those landing here now, you are almost certainly using python 2.6 or greater, so you can use the built-in json module [for Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) (or [for Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html), since Google recently added support for Python 3 on GAE). Importing is as easy as `import json`. Here are some examples of how to use the json module:

```
import json

# parse json_string into a dict
json_string = '{"key_one": "value_one", "key_two": 1234}'
json_dict = json.loads(json_string)
# json_dict: {u'key_two': 1234, u'key_one': u'value_one'}

# generate json from a dict
json_dict = {'key': 'value', 'key_two': 1234, 'key_three': True}
json_string = json.dumps(json_dict)
# json_string: '{"key_two": 1234, "key": "value", "key_three": true}'
```

If you are using an older version of python, stick to @Brian M. Hunt's answer.

Again, here is the doc page for the json module for [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html), and here it is for [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html).

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Python2.6 or greater, I've used with success the built-in [json](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html).load function. Otherwise, [simplejson](http://code.google.com/p/simplejson/) works on 2.4 without dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the python section of [json.org](http://json.org/). The standard library support for JSON started at python 2.6, which I believe is newer than what the app engine provides. Maybe one of the other options listed?

Comment: That's not really relevant to App Engine.