# How can I use json module in google app engine?

Tags: python, json, google-app-engine, python-2.5

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I parse JSON in Google App Engine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171584/how-can-i-parse-json-in-google-app-engine)

json module  was added in python 2.6 but GAE supports 2.5 only.

How can I use it there?

Comment: @Brian And you waited 1 yr. for... what?

Comment: First time I saw this question was 58 mins ago. :)

Comment: It means mine was more "searchable"  ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you wotn be able to use the standard python library, you will have to use some third party lib such as

- [jyson](http://opensource.xhaus.com/news/5) or
- [simplejson](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/simplejson/)

At least simplejson works on python 2.4

Comment: Ok, now complementary question, how can I use it? I mean, how do I bundle this module with my app ( I'm starting with python as you can see )

Comment: I've never done it before, but you GAE does give you the ability to add your own modules,

have a look at the GAE FAQ, http://code.google.com/appengine/kb/commontasks.html they describe how it is done there

Comment: Great, looking at it. I also create a question specifically for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2511883/bundle-module-with-app-on-google-app-engine

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `yaml` module (which is included in GAE) as JSON parser. YAML in recent version is superset of JSON.

```
>>> import yaml
>>> yaml.load('[false, null, {"x": 1}]')
[False, None, {'x': 1}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using django.utils.simplejson