# Bundle module with app on Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

This may be a basic question but how can I include a module with my app.

I'm very new to python and what I want to do is to include this module [simplejson](https://pypi.org/project/simplejson/) with my app, but after downloading it I have no idea what to do next :(

This is how the module looks like after unzip it.

I don't know what files to move to my app.

[image: This is the unzipped module]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put the `simplejson` directory (that is inside the `simplejson-2.1.0`) in your app.

Or, you could just use the `simplejson` lib that's bundled with the Django lib that's bundled with App Engine by doing the following import wherever you need it:

```
from django.utils import simplejson
```

That's always available, without needing to bundle anything extra with your app.  The only drawback I can think of is that it will be out of date (though I don't know how far out of date).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I did both and for now ( since I'm learning ) I'll use the one that comes with django. Eventually I might need the other and is good to know how to use it.

Comment: I'm glad I could help.  I too would just use the one that's already available until I ran into some limitation that could be overcome by bundling your own, newer, version of `simplejson`.

Answer (score 1):

Put the directory (or a link) into your deployment directory and `appcfg.py update` will send it along to the server. This is documented in the [Python Runtime Environment](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/runtime.html#Pure_Python) page.

Comment: erh.... what file? the whole .tar.gz????? nahh.. the simplejson directory?  :( seems very easy and yet I don't have a clue :(

Comment: Yes, the unpacked simplejson directory itself. Experiment on it with dev_appserver first because it is easier.

Comment: Thanks you. I figure out a minute later :P  and after reading the link you posted I saw I can also use symbolic link :)