# Google App Engine: JSON module

Tags: python, django, json, google-app-engine

I'm using JSON with [Google App Engine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_App_Engine).

I'm using JSON for comunication, so on the Python side I have:

```
import json
```

The error I'm getting is this:

> <class 'django.core.exceptions.ViewDoesNotExist'>: Could not import views.ganttapp. Error was: No module named json

In my stand-alone this works great. Is there any problem with JSON on Google App Engine? Or should I use another module?

I don't know if you can open this, but here it goes: http://ganttapp.appspot.com/newgantt. You can find the error here.

Comment: json joined the standard library in Python 2.6; App Engine uses Python 2.5.  It's a good idea to use 2.5 in your development environment to avoid code that "works great" in development and doesn't work when deployed.

Comment: This is a duplicate of "How can I parse JSON in Google App Engine?": http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171584

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Maybe you can import the [Django](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29) [simplejson](http://docs.nullpobug.com/django/trunk/django.utils.simplejson-module.html) wrapper:

```
from django.utils import simplejson
```

Comment: This is indeed the answer, from the official docs: http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/rpc.html (also the first hit for [app engine json] in Google)