# GAE + Javascript push : multiline to push

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have this in the Google App Engine python code,

```
class ABC(db.Model):
  StringA = db.StringProperty()
  StringB = db.StringProperty(multiline=True)

abcs = ABC.all()
template_values = {'abcs': abcs,}
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'index.html')
self.response.out.write(template.render(path, template_values))
```

and this in the index.html,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 var string_A = [];
 var string_B = [];

{% for abc in abcs %}
 string_A.push("{{ abc.StringA }}");
 string_B.push("{{ abc.StringB }}");  //This doesn't work?
{% endfor %}
</script>
```

My question is that how to I push the multiline to the array??

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Multiline is a little bit tricky on Javascript,  replacing '\n' with '\' in string_B should work.

Comment: Only replacing \n would solve the issue for newlines, but it would leave other characters (e.g. quotaion marks), and a potential XSS vulnerability.

Answer (score 1):

If you are generating a Javascript expression, you need to be careful to escape the string so you always get a valid Javascript expression and you don't introduce a XSS vulnerability (in case the strings are provided by users). You can use the [addslashes](http://www.djangoproject.com/documentation/0.96/templates/#addslashes) Django template filter to escape special chars for a Javascript string:

```
string_B.push("{{ abc.StringB|addslashes }}");
```

An alternative solution is to use json to generate a safe and properly escaped javascript expression containing all the data you'll need in the Javascript code. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171584/how-can-i-parse-json-in-google-app-engine) about using json on GAE. Using json you can write something like:

```
from django.utils import simplejson as json
class ABC(db.Model):
    # [...]
    def as_json(self):
        return json.dumps({'StringA':self.StringA, 'StringB':self.StringB})
```

And at the template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var abcs = [];
{% for abc in abcs %}
abcs.push({{ abc.as_json }});
{% endfor %}
</script>
```

This way you get all the data you'll need from the abc objects in a single array.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of templating library are you using? I think that's auto escaping issue. You should try like this if you a using Django tempalte on GAE.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var string_A = [];
var string_B = [];

{% for abc in abcs %}
string_A.push("{{ abc.StringA }}");
{%autoescape off}
 string_B.push("{{ abc.StringB }}");
{%endautoescape%}
{% endfor %}
</script>
```

Good luck!

Comment: I don't think it is an autoescaping issue, but an issue of *not* properly escaping the values.