# Can't deploy my app to Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

how am I supposed to import `json` on Google App Engine? My project works fine locally, but I just can't deploy it online. Here is my code:

```
import json
self.response.out.write(json.dumps(Jsonobject))
```

and this is the snippet from the log:

```
<type 'exceptions.ImportError'>: No module named json
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/base/data/home/apps/clinteney/1.349424641588618637/Main.py", line 4, in <module>
import json
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If it works locally, you're probably not using python 2.5, which is a bad idea if you want the same stuff to work locally and on the production servers.

Comment: @Clinteney The 'json' module is a 2.7 feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try replacing the first line with

```
import simplejson
```

Google App Engine only supports certain packages when running on production.

Comment: Thank, btw, where can I find what packages google supports? Thank you

Answer (score 1):

[Brian M. Hunt says:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1171584/how-can-i-parse-json-in-google-app-engine/1171730#1171730)

```
from django.utils import simplejson as json
```