# How do I deploy my Google App Engine project when not behind a proxy in Python 2.7 despite this urllib2 error?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, deployment, web-deployment

From this question ( [Can't deploy my app to Google App Engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520603/cant-deploy-my-app-to-google-app-engine) ), I see that perhaps some imports aren't allowed on production GAE.  I've cut down to the following:

```
import webapp2 # Comes with latest GAE w/ Python 2.7
import os # for loading appropriate files on the server

from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.api import channel
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import template
```

I'm not directly linking to a website in my Python script.  This is the only line where I refer to a file.

```
path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'myfile.html')
```

I'm working at home, not behind a proxy.  Despite all these things that I've seen as factors in other questions on SO and in various search results, I continue getting the following error.

```
2012-10-11 13:22:01,890 ERROR appcfg.py:2182 An error occurred processing file '':
<urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>. Aborting. 
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 171, in <module>
run_file(__file__, globals())

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\appcfg.py", line 167, in run_file
execfile(script_path, globals_)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 4191, in <module>
main(sys.argv)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 4182, in main
result = AppCfgApp(argv).Run()

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2579, in Run
self.action(self)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3927, in __call__
return method()

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3041, in Update
self.UpdateVersion(rpcserver, self.basepath, appyaml)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 3023, in UpdateVersion
lambda path: self.opener(os.path.join(basepath, path), 'rb'))

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 2152, in DoUpload
self.resource_limits = GetResourceLimits(self.rpcserver, self.config)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 357, in GetResourceLimits
resource_limits.update(GetRemoteResourceLimits(rpcserver, config))

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appcfg.py", line 328, in GetRemoteResourceLimits
version=config.version)

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\google\appengine\tools\appengine_rpc.py", line 383, in Send
f = self.opener.open(req)

File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 400, in open
url = rest

File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 418, in _open
user_passwd = unquote(user_passwd)

File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 378, in _call_chain
"""Default error handler: close the connection and raise IOError."""

File "C:\Python27\lib\urllib2.py", line 1215, in https_open
s += unichr(int(item[:2], 16)) + item[2:]

File "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\google_appengine\lib\fancy_urllib\fancy_urllib\__init__.py", 
    line 383, in do_open
raise url_error

urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>
2012-10-11 13:22:01 (Process exited with code 1)
```

So there's the error, and I really don't think it's on my end because of how minimal I've made my code.  To recap:

- Unlike other questions and their unmarked solutions, I'm not behind a proxy;
- I don't have any internet URLs in my python script;
- I'm using Python 2.7 and the Deploy button on the Google App Engine launcher.

One solution I haven't tried is setting an environment variable (http_proxy, https_proxy) to my proxy because I don't know what proxy to set it to; I don't have one.  In my project settings, I have https://myappname.appspot.com as the Deployment Server.

How do I proceed?  Any red flags you can identify immediately from what I've described?

Note:

- Since starting to write this and continually clicking on more suggestions from StackOverflow, I've tried setting a new environment variable http_proxy to my IP, my IP:8080, and "host_or_ip:port" (from question [How can I disable the automatic checking for updates when Google App Engine Launcher is started?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6468191/google-app-engine-launcher-slow-to-launch-behind-proxy-possibly-because-of-ch)).
- I'll be trying the same values with https_proxy while you good folks read and put out your ideas.

Comment: The deployment process doesn't care what imports or URLs you use in your code. That's only a problem when you try to actually run the code you've uploaded to AppEngine.

Comment: Thanks for confirming that.  It definitely isn't my own use of urllib2 nor any urlfetch() methods; I brought that up because in my research so far, I've been seeing that it's directly a Python issue and people experienced the 11004 error in their own scripts.  Glad to have you confirm that my usage is definitely not a factor as we figure this out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're using the correct development server.

It should be: http://appengine.google.com

Comment: Hooray for Google App Engine IRC.  Thanks for the response; oddly enough, this simple factor is mentioned in no other question about error 11004.

Comment: Now in 2015, I have to use "appengine.google.com" only. Google app engine launcher always add http://