# android post json, app engine gives 404

Tags: android, python, json, http-status-code-404

Im trying to learn more about webbbservices and python at the same time. 
So if you got ideas or solution, explain to me like Im 5. :)

So I want to send a string to the server and just store it in a database (guestbook). 
I've managed to do this with a webpage but now I want to access and store a string by phone, this is the python code:

```
import os
import urllib
import json

from google.appengine.ext import ndb

import jinja2
import webapp2


JINJA_ENVIRONMENT = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
    extensions=['jinja2.ext.autoescape'],
    autoescape=True)

DEFAULT_GUESTBOOK_NAME = 'default_guestbook'
GUESTBOOKS_NAME = 'guestbook'

def guestbook_key(guestbook_name=DEFAULT_GUESTBOOK_NAME):
    return ndb.Key('Guestbook', guestbook_name)


class Guestbook(ndb.Model):
    identity = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True


class Chat(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):

        guestbook = Guestbook(parent=guestbook_key(GUESTBOOKS_NAME))
        guestbook.identity=self.request.get("content") 
        guestbook.put()
        self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "text/plain"
        self.response.out.write("ok")

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
    (r'/chat', Chat),
], debug=True)
```

and this is the android code:

```
private void sendData(){

        try {
            JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject();
            jsonobj.put("content", "asdf1234");

            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppostreq = new HttpPost("http://<myappid>.appspot.com/chat/");

            StringEntity se = new StringEntity(jsonobj.toString());

            se.setContentType("application/json;charset=UTF-8");
            se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE,"application/json;charset=UTF-8"));

            httppostreq.setEntity(se);

            HttpResponse httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppostreq);

            Log.d("Debug", "Response: " + EntityUtils.toString(httpresponse.getEntity()));

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e){
            Log.d("Debug", "Exception: " + e.getMessage());
        }


    }
```

Comment: your regex requires (+ one or more) digits to be passed in the chat url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your routing table : `(r'/chat/(\d+)', Chat),` this line maps the url to the handler.

which is handled by mapping the `(\d+)` to `product_id` in the get function of the handler.

valid urls

- /chat/1
- /chat/302490205

invalid urls

- /chat
- /chat/jedi

**edit**

since your posting your need a post method in your handler

```
def post(self):
    #do stuff
```

Comment: So, if I remove d+ I get a 405 instead... :S

Comment: Did you remove the product I'd?

Comment: I've updated the question. The problem now is setting "guestbook.identity=???????"

Comment: Updated once more. :)

Comment: I changed to "get" to "post" but I dont seem to be able to read the data. :S

Comment: I solved it, found a solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15763660/python-google-app-engine-receiving-a-string-in-stead-of-json-object